# Power Shell Invoke-SQLSelect : Exception calling "Fill" with "1" argument(s):

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am getting this error while running a power shell script

> Invoke-SQLSelect : Exception calling "Fill" with "1" argument(s):
> "Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to
> completion of the operation or the server is not  responding."

```
# Import functions file for Database Access
Import-Module C:\apps\powerShell\RLID\SQLDatabaseAccess.ps1 -Force

$Connection=Connect-SQLServer -InstanceName "GP-SQLDB-300,33416" -DatabaseName "VepoBackFlow" -IntegratedSecurity $true

Invoke-SQLSelect -Connection $Connection -SelectStatement "EXECUTE dbo.UpdateVepoMeterNum"

Invoke-SQLSelect -Connection $Connection -SelectStatement "EXECUTE dbo.InsertLogRecord 'CompareMeter.ps1','Insert Row to VEPO_OUT', 'ew1844','execute dbo.UpdateVepoMeterNum'"

Close-SQLServerConeection -Connection $Connection
```

Comment: Check the code in `SQLDatabaseAccess.ps1` to see if it has a command timeout parameter for `Invoke-SQLSelect`. Otherwise, you'll need to tune your query so that it runs in less than 30 seconds (the default command timeout), or just use ADO.NET objects instead of the helper code.

Answer (score 0):

After trying many things, I found the solution  by programmatically setting the time out to 10 minutes, that seems to solve the issue.

```
$SQLCommand.CommandTimeout = 640
```